Are there locking headers in Autodesk Fusion 360? (Electronics design)
I'm making a PCB for a project of mine using Autodesk's Fusion 360, and I'm looking for some connectors to plug other PCBs into. I've had my eye on some Imperial Locking Headers but I can't find any in Fusion's Libraries. I've searched the Library Manager for 'connector', 'imperial', 'locking header' and some other stuff, but I can't find any. Does Autodesk Fusion have these?

Why not make your own symbol for them?

No 1: Use your own libraries. Always. Copy from existing libraries if you want, but control your own library. || No 2: If you have searched for the name and the part number - evidently it's not there. How could a Q/A site make any difference?

@Hearth Rather new tu Fusion Electronics and I'm not entirely sure how to do it, but I'd love some tutorials/documentation if you know any good ones!

@MrGerber I've seen the headers come under quite a few different names, thought I'd throw it out here and see if I should be doing anything differently.

@GillP I've never used Fusion; I will never use an Autodesk product (they are one of the worst companies out there).

im tempted to report that just for you saying that... :D alright ill have a look around

Sparkfun probably has some in their libraries. And there is Wurth WR-WTB.

Had a look, and I wouldn't be suprised if that's true!  that's a LOT of connectors...

Yes, Wurth's library has exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!
